# Deluge can't open torrents

Tags: python, torrent

Deluge stopped adding torrents, either from magnet links or even clicking on "Add torrent" menu option. This is on Ubuntu 16.04. Checking on the log I got the following:

```
Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/addtorrentdialog.py", line 157, in show
    return self.update_core_config(True, focus)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/addtorrentdialog.py", line 202, in update_core_config
    return client.core.get_config_values(self.core_keys).addCallback(_on_config_values)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 317, in addCallback
    callbackKeywords=kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 306, in addCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/addtorrentdialog.py", line 197, in _on_config_values
    self.set_default_options()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/ui/gtkui/addtorrentdialog.py", line 496, in set_default_options
    self.core_config["move_completed_path"]
exceptions.TypeError: Gtk.FileChooser.set_current_folder() argument 1 must be string, not None
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Gtk.FileChooser.set_current_folder()` requires a string parameter, so that's what you should be passing.

Comment: You are absolutely right. So, somehow the folders in Preferences -> Downloads became empty. To solve this, just add a desired folder to each of the options. The exception ceases after this and torrents can be added again.

Answer (score 2):

As I replyed to njzk2: 
You are absolutely right. So, somehow the folders in Preferences -> Downloads became empty. To solve this, just add a desired folder to each of the options. The exception ceases after this and torrents can be added again.